# Run an SSRS report from a Power BI passing parameters

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

Exist the possibility to execute "***SSRS Reports***" from **Power BI Dashboard**, sending parameter values to execute SSRS report with these parameters?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0qfF.png)

Comment: You can pass parameters to an SSRS report through the URL. There is no direct integration other than that.

Comment: But, can you explain the step by steo to do this?
I don't know how to capture the filtered value

Comment: It depends on your environment and if you are in native or integrated mode. It will require some research, but there are resources available now that you know what to search for.